# Where I can found org.testng.TestNg package in testng framework using Eclipse IDE for Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I am designing a customized automation framework for testing, using Selenium Webdriver and Java.

Now for reporting purpose I am trying to integrate TestNG framework with my project.

Now I am having a GUI based interface which is containing some specifications, where particular feature and testcases can be selected. Now I need to run this application first,then in turn it is going to trigger the TestNG framework using testng.xml .

So I need to know how I should do this thing ?

And also through different links I found to run the testng.xml some package named org.testng.TestNg is required, But I am not able to figure it out where it is existing?

Comment: Where can I get org.testng.TestNG package ? If this package is not correct one ,then which one I should use ? Please comment..

Answer (score 1):

You may need to include testng jar file in your project to get the package. You can create testng.xml programatically refer this [link](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically).

Also you can run tests by adding a class having main function as below :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    org.testng.TestNG.main(args);
}
```

Where arguments will be testNG arguments e.g. `java org.testng.TestNG testng1.xml [testng2.xml testng3.xml ...]`

Update :
To start using maven you can refer this [link](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html). If you are using Elipse IDE than you can also configure Maven with using M2E plugin for eclipse. To confuigure Eclipse with maven please refere [link](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/download/).

Now to use Maven with testNG and selenium you need to configure your Maven pom.xml file to inculde testNG and Selenium webdriver dependancies. Second please add my above main function in your class to run Testng form Jar. Now using maven build commands please create a jar file for your project. Maven provides variety of plugins and you can use some of them as per your use. However I will suggest you use maven-jar-plugin,maven-assembly-plugin.

Once you will run the Maven commands. the jar or zip will be created in Target folder in your project directory. You can run jar using java-jar jarname testng.xml.

Comment: I have tried this thing but giving error like this  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

Comment: Please try configuring your projects using maven, it seeems to me that testNG jar is not configured in your project's classpath. Maven will help you to add the dependencies like testNG and selenium in your project. Also please let me know how you are trying to run your test I mean the command or program?

Comment: I am setting my ProjectPath and classpath like this :

Comment: I am setting my ProjectPath and classpath like this:               set ProjectPath =  D:\TestNG\TestNGSuite\Lib\*                                                                     set classpath=%ProjectPath%\bin;%ProjectPath%\Lib\*                                                                                                                                   The Lib folder is created manually by me. It is containing two folders named org.testng.eclipse_6.8.6.20130914_0724(as I have installed the TestNG as a Eclipse plugin from eclipse ide) and selenium-2.37.0.

Comment: But still the error is coming. By testng.xml file is kept in the ProjectPath only,where I have set that thing. So from where the issue is coming I am not getting, please help me out.........

Comment: Ok, You need to have your test classes at the same location as your testng jar and xml. testNG jar doesn't understand the path for your test class from xml. If yor are creating a jar than you need to have testNG jar path added to mainfest file.

Comment: Hi, I am using the full path of testng.jar file and testng.xml file, but still issue is not getting resolved. One thing I have tried that if I run the testng.xml file within the Eclipse IDE, then it is working very fine. But when I am using from the command prompt it is not working. It is showing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException. So what to do right now? Please  help me out..

Comment: please try this command after going to the directory of testng jar file Java -cp "path of test class zip/jar" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

Comment: Could you please try configuring testNG jar in your classpath using maven or Ant. I faced the similar issue but got resolved when i used Maven for integration.

Comment: Please describe me how to integrate ANT,TestNG and Eclipse with each other. Please tell me in detail,step by step....I want to try this thing.....

Comment: Updated my answer above, Since using maven is very vast but I tried to reply specific to testing. please let me know in case you need more help. Also, please read as much as possible to use maven online.